# How to Bind Selected Item in ListBox to PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, picturebox

I don't know if "bind" is the word to be used. But I want to learn how to code it.

Expected output, selecting the item in the listbox will automatically display an image in your picturebox.

[image]

*Selecting the item car in the listbox[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a class to define your data

```vb
Public Class Thing
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Image As Bitmap
    Public Sub New(name As String, image As Bitmap)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Image = image
    End Sub
End Class
```

then use this code to bind the ListBox. You'll need to specify where the images from from instead of `New Bitmap("Car.jpg")` etc.

```vb
Private things As New List(Of Thing)()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    things.Add(New Thing("Car", New Bitmap("Car.jpg")))
    things.Add(New Thing("House", New Bitmap("House.jpg")))
    things.Add(New Thing("Money", New Bitmap("Money.jpg")))
    things.Add(New Thing("People", New Bitmap("People.jpg")))
    bindListBox()
End Sub

Private Sub bindListBox()
    Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    Me.ListBox1.DataSource = things
End Sub
```

and an event handler to change the image depending on the selection in the ListBox

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Dim thing = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Thing)
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = thing.Image
End Sub
```